# How to set cloudwatch to link my data point

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch

I upload some data points to aws cloudwatch and `Line` widget.

I choose `Action -> Link Graphs` and doesn't work.

**Action -> Link Graphs**

[image: Action -> Link Graphs]

**The first two data points are linked, but not the rests**

[image: The first two data points are linked, but not the rests]

Comment: I have the same question - would love an answer if this is possible!

Comment: @nlml The answer has already been provided. You haven't explained what's wrong with it.

Comment: It doesn't explain how to linearly interpolate between all points. The other answer just explains what the Link Graphs feature does.

Answer (score 6):

The question is about connecting the datapoints in the graph with a line.
Gaps in your graph tell you that there are no datapoints for those timestamps. As mickzer explained, drawing a line where there are no datapoints has nothing to do with the **Link graphs** feature from the screenshot.

To have CloudWatch bridge the gaps in your metric, you can use the `FILL()` [metric math](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/using-metric-math.html) function.

Let's say this is your data:

[image]

You can fill the gaps:

- with a static value (0 in this case):

[image]

- by repeating the last value:

[image]

- linearly interpreting the missing values:

[image]

Comment: FILL(METRICS(), LINEAR) is what I was looking for - thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You've misunderstood the feature.

This features allows you to link graphs on your dashboard together, so that when you zoom in or zoom out on one graph, the other graphs zoom in or zoom out at the same time.

See the docs:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/link_unlink_graph_dashboard.html

I don't believe there is a way to join these datapoints together at this metric period. You might get a prettier graph if you increase the period, but that way you might loose some of the detail.